# Rspec test controller with rails 4, fail after update for routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm upgrading a Rails app from 3.2 to 4.0.4, I had some test on controllers that was working perfectly on the 3.2 version, now they fails due to a No Route Match error. I wonder what has to do routes when I'm testing my controller.

I have a nested route like this:

```
  resources :projects, only: [:index, :show, :create, :edit], shallow: true do
    resources :tasks, only: [:create, :index, :show, :edit, :update]
  end
```

On my tasks controller spec I have this, and it fails after the update, was working on rails 3.2:

rspec

```
describe 'with no project/id parameter' do
  it 'json code is assigned to invalid parameters' do
    params = valid_params
    params.delete(:project_id)
    post :create params
    expect(assigns(:json_code)).to eq(INVALID_PARAMS)
  end
end
```

However after the upgrade this fails, this is the message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tasks", :format=>"json"}
```

So seems like on the previous version the routes was not getting evaluated. I know this could barely happen on a real escenario, but if I accidentally missmap a route to that action is possible that the action get called without the project_id param.

So what are the solution, or the right approach to write this test?

Answer (score 0):

Run `rake routes` and you will see that route for `create` is with `POST` HTTP verb.

In your example, you are calling `create` as a `get` request, there is no route like that. So you get the error as `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"tasks", :format=>"json"}`

Just change your example as below:

```
describe 'with no project/id parameter' do
  it 'json code is assigned to invalid parameters' do
    params = valid_params
    params.delete(:project_id)
    post :create params          ## post request
    expect(assigns(:json_code)).to eq(INVALID_PARAMS)
  end
end
```

> if I accidentally missmap a route to that action is possible that the
>   action get called without the project_id param.

You are deleting the `:project_id` from params hash , so you will always get the error as no route would match. `create` route requires `project_id` to be passed, if its not passed then you won't have a matching route and `create` action would never be called.

Comment: You are right, i made a mistake asking because in the code i have something like send(verb, path, params), I simplified it, and should write post, not get. So I'm really calling post.

Comment: You are deleting the `:project_id` from params hash , so you will always get the error as no route would match. `create` action would never be called.

Comment: Yes, but why it works on rails 3.2 before the upgrade to 4? rspec dont evaluate routes on that rails versions?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa That's what I'm trying to figure out too. If you have any ideas, let me know!